# Docker no such file or directory

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm trying to write a very simple and straightforward docker file for a Golang application. But for some reason it is giving me this error when trying to run the image:

`exec /app/serverTest: no such file or directory`

I can't figure out what is wrong with it, searched for similar questions but no luck solving the issue.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
## Build
FROM golang:1.20 AS build

WORKDIR /tmp/build

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o ./out/serverTest .

## Deploy
FROM golang:alpine

COPY --from=build /tmp/build/out/serverTest /app/serverTest

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/serverTest"]
```

I've tried giving +x permissions, using CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT, changing names/folders, among other things..

Some idea on what the problem could be?

Comment: After the `COPY --from=build ...` command. add `RUN chmod +x /app/serverTest` and see if that works.

Comment: Yup. I've tried that before asking (tried again now just in case). Didn't worked

Comment: Also, verify if between stages you got a message "Removing intermediate container XXXX" . And add a slash at the end of paths... /tmp/build/out/serverTest/   /app/serverTest/

Comment: could you run it so?: `docker build --progress=plain -t your-app-name .` to see all build logs

Comment: Found the issue. Seems like the executable file wont run with alpine :S. Dunno why, but if I change golang:alpine to debian:latest, it will work

Comment: Try: `RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build with:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o ./out/serverTest .
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the executable file wont run with alpine. Dunno why, but if I change golang:alpine to debian:latest, it works